# 'New' disappeared from all the context menus in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, context-menu

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 (SP2) machine. Today onwards 'New' option disappeared from all the context menus. Because of this I cannot create a new folder, text document, word document or anything.

The following screenshot is the context menu in the desktop.

[image]

I searched for solutions, but most of the solutions are for Windows 7. How can I get back the 'New' option in the context menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself from this link: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-new-menuitem-in-desktop-and-explorer-context-menu/

When I checked the link there was 2 methods. First method described to do editings in the registry which was not successful. The second method allowed me to download a file which contains a registry key. After downloading I double clicked the registry key and it asked for permission, which I granted. Everything is ok now.